# Stochastic optimization and mean field games : textbooks

Tags: stochastic-calculus, market-microstructure, market-making, stochastic-control

Which textbooks and online courses would you recommend to learn :

- stochastic optimization
- mean field games
  applied to quantitative finance.

My goal would be to read research articles like the ones written by Dr [Emma Hubert](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.10405.pdf)
I am familiar with stochastic calculus. I may prefer an online course, with corrected exercises, instead of a textbook. There are several textbooks. Which one could provide an introduction ?

Some textbooks :

- Fleming H. and M. Soner (1993). Controlled Markov processes and viscosity solutions. Springer
- Oksendal B. and A. Sulem (2006). Applied Stochastic Control Of Jump Diffusions. Springer
- Dimitri P. Bertsekas (1995). Dynamic programming and optimal control. Athena Scientific

Comment: You mention that there are several textbooks. Can you please list them here.

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question. A starting point would be :
the summer school on mean field games, provided by the University of Chicago.

[summer school](https://www.imsi.institute/imfga21/)